# displaying data in ListView programmatically

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android App and I need to display some data in a scrollable Listview.
I will extract some strings from objects that I right now have stored in linked lists (until i come up with a better solution).

I want to display a view that looks almost like the contacts app. A list with a small picture to the left and a larger text to the right of the picture with a smaller text the bigger one. When I click on one of the items it should open a new activity.

How do I create the view? If I adds an object in the linked list it should appear in the list.

I have checked some sample code, but they all uses Arrayadapter and I dont understand how I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article about Adapters: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
If you want to add new objects in ListVew use:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChenged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the libraries in this question, you have what you need there:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)